# How to Bottom Center a TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I don't understand why the widget isn't being placed at the bottom of the screen, from my understanding the line " crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end" should place it there. Can anyone offer help?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, //why isn't this placing the widget at the end
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(

              )
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Row`'s height equals height of `TextField` and you're trying to align its content to the bottom. You can see it by wrapping it in colored container:

[image: 1]

Instead of aligning inside of Row, you need to align the Row itself inside of parent Container:

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, // align the row
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
              )
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
```

[image: 2]

Comment: Thank you so much your explanation was perfect !